# Regex to transform urls to hyperlinks on user input

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I have a working regex that takes a user input such as "Please follow this link: http://www.google.com or this link https://www.google.com." and turns the urls into hyperlinks. Notice period at the end of user input. I need to know how to ignore a period at the end of the sentence so that the last url ends up as https://www.test2.com and not https://www.test2.com.

```
vm.transformText = (text) ->
  return text.replace(/(https:\/\/|http:\/\/)([\w\.\?\+\=\/]+)/g, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1$2\">$1$2</a>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your pattern can be refactored so that you could change it easier to your needs.

The `https:\/\/|http:\/\/` alternation can be reduced to a short `https?:\/\/` where `s` is made optional (`?` makes a pattern match 1 or 0 times).

The `[\w\.\?\+\=\/]+` part is overescaped. You only need to escape `/` (actually, even this char inside a character class may be left unescaped).

If you just want to stop matching before a `.`, use

```
/(https?:\/\/)([\w.?+=\/]*[\w?+=\/])/g
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0gtxo/2)

Here, `[\w.?+=\/]+` is turned into `[\w.?+=\/]*[\w?+=\/]`: 0 or more word, dot, `?`, `+`, `=` or `/` chars followed with a word, `?`, `+`, `=` or `/` char.